# Why can't I add a namespaced event handler after removing one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-namespaces

In one file (that I can't edit), there's an event that is added with a namespace:

```
$('p').on('ns.click',function(){
   // do stuff
});
```

I'd like to remove that handler and add a different one in the same namespace. Here's what I've done:

```
$('p').off('ns.click')
      .on('ns.click',function(){
            // do different stuff
      });
```

This does *not* work.

If there is no namespace, this works as expected (just using 'click' for both `on` and `off`):

```
$('p').off('click')
      .on('click',function(){
            // do different stuff
      });
```

Also, if I add a new handler with a *different* namespace, it works as expected:

```
$('p').off('ns.click')
      .on('xyz.click',function(){
            // do different stuff
      });
```

**Why can't I remove the namespaced handler then re-add a new one?**

Comment: namespaces should come after the event name (`cilck.ns`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/on/ namespaces are set after the event name, not before, so it should be `click.ns`